# SQL GroupBy returning inconsistent (alternating) results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have the following code, and after running it a few times a realized it's returning alternating results and I don't understand why:

```
DECLARE @M_ID CHAR(8) = '12345678';
DECLARE @C_ID TINYINT = 1;
DECLARE @StartDate CHAR(14) = '20160726000000';
DECLARE @EndDate CHAR(14) = '20160825235959';

DECLARE @ActivePresent FLOAT;
DECLARE @ActivePresent_DT CHAR(14);

SELECT 
    @ActivePresent = MAX(ActivePowerPresent), 
    @ActivePresent_DT = [DateTime]
FROM
    EnergyDemand
WHERE 
    M_ID = @M_ID 
    AND C_ID = @C_ID 
    AND ([DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY 
    [DateTime]

SELECT @ActivePresent, @ActivePresent_DT
```

The result alternates between 2 values...

```
0.00 (20160824195408) and 210.04 (20160815085655)
```

What I am trying to do:

Get the highest value in the table and the corresponding datetime that value occurred, based on `M_ID = @M_ID`, `C_ID = @C_ID` and between the given date range,

***NOTE:** I am storing datetime values as char(14) because they have to be in indexes...

Perhaps my heading is wrong, because it's consistently "inconsistent", hmmm...

Even an alternative way to retrieve the data I require would be much appreciated. But an explanation why, for the win... I would have thought the `WHERE` clause runs before the `GROUP BY` since that's it's order of execution and therefore it's using the exact same result set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add some sample data for us to test

Comment: `I am storing datetime values as char(14) because they have to be in indexes` ... I'm not a database expert, but this sounds like a really bad idea to me.  You could store your dates as numerical timestamps.  I think certain types of indices would still work, and working with those dates would still be feasible.

Comment: Also: since you don't have any `ORDER BY` clause, there's no guaranteed ordering of any kind - so it's totally thinkable that different values will be returned at different points in time.... if you need to get *the highest value* - then there *should be* some kind of ordering in place!

Comment: What makes you think you cannot index `DATETIME`?

Comment: Lol, @TimBiegeleisen -  A senior said so and I took their word for gold... thanks all, glad I mentioned it though else who knows how long I would continue believing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `TOP 1` with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @ActivePresent = ActivePowerPresent, @ActivePresent_DT = [DateTime]
FROM EnergyDemand
WHERE M_ID = @M_ID AND C_ID = @C_ID AND 
      ([DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
ORDER BY ActivePowerPresent DESC
```

**Note:** You should store `datetime` values in their native format and not as `CHAR(14)`. SQL Server can index `datetime` fields, just like any other RDBMS that I know of.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was over complicating things... The index part - took a senior's word for gold, glad I mentioned it thought, else I would have continued following uneducated for who knows how long!

Comment: I will definitely challenge the architects decision, So I could definitely expect performance improvements since internally it stores datetime as 2 integers (which I KNOW the DB loves for indexes) right?

Comment: @EaziLuizi SQL Server uses 8 bytes to store `DATETIME`, whereas your system as it is right now uses 14! It's 6 bytes more just to store something in an implicit way!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your group by statement returning multiple records and you are assigning it to one variable. Please use order by in your statement for consistent behaviour.

```
SELECT 
    @ActivePresent = MAX(ActivePowerPresent), 
    @ActivePresent_DT = [DateTime]
FROM
    EnergyDemand
WHERE 
    M_ID = @M_ID 
    AND C_ID = @C_ID 
    AND ([DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY 
   [DateTime]
ORDER BY
    [DateTime]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just going to get the last value read and you have no order by